# How to create a new column based off OR and AND statements in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

```
        None       Pain    Swelling    Tiredness     Headache     Nausea     Malaise     Lymph
1        0         1          0             0            0          0           1         0
2        0         0          1             0            0          0           0         0
3        0         0          0             0            1          0           0         0
4        1         0          0             0            0          0           0         0
5        1         0          1             0            0          0           0         0
6        0         1          0             1            0          0           0         0
```

I have a df above with symptoms. I would like to make a new data frame that creates a column "OnlyPainOrSwelling" that is also binary. I would like a 1 in the column if EITHER pain or swelling has a 1, however, if there are any other symptoms then I would like a 0 in the column. For example, in row 6, there is a pain symptom, but there is also tiredness, so I would like to have a 0 in the new column. I have tried OR and AND statements to no avail. Help?

New df:

```
        None       Pain    Swelling    Tiredness     Headache     Nausea     Malaise     Lymph   OnlyPainorSwelling
1        0         1          0             0            0          0           1         0          1
2        0         0          1             0            0          0           0         0          1
3        0         0          0             0            1          0           0         0          0 
4        1         0          0             0            0          0           0         0          0
5        0         0          1             0            0          0           0         0          1
6        0         1          0             1            0          0           0         0          0
```

I have tried:

```
df$OnlyPainorSwelling <- 1L * (df$Pain == 1 |
                        df$Swelling == 1 &
                        df$Tiredness == 0 &
                        df$Headache == 0 &
                        df$Nausea = 0 &
                        df$Malaise == 0 &
                        df$Lymph == 0 &)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing parentheses around the Pain and Swelling part. Also you have an extra `&` at the end. Fixing these, we can get this:

```
df$OnlyPainorSwelling <- 1L * (
    (df$Pain == 1 | df$Swelling == 1 ) &
    df$Tiredness == 0 &
    df$Headache == 0 &
    df$Nausea = 0 &
    df$Malaise == 0 &
    df$Lymph == 0
)
```

However, for readability I would recommend this approach instead:

```
pain_swell = c("Pain", "Swelling")
other_symptoms = c("Tiredness", "Headache", "Nausea", "Malaise", "Lymph")

df$OnlyPainorSwelling <- as.integer(
  rowSums(df[pain_swell]) > 0 & rowSums(df[other_symptoms]) == 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**A dplyr solution**

dplyr's `if_any` and `if_all` are excellent choices for rowwise logical operations on data.frames, which makes the code very easy to understand and implement.
Using the vectors specified by @Gregor Thomas, we can use `dplyr::if_any`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(onlyPainOrSwelling = +(if_any(pain_swell) & !if_any(other_symptoms)))
```

In this solution, we also benefit from the implicit coercion of numeric variables to logical (0's are coerced to FALSE, 1's to TRUE).
We can make it more explicit with `.x==1`:

```
df %>% mutate(onlyPainOrSwelling = +(if_any(pain_swell, ~.x==1) & !if_any(other_symptoms, ~.x==1))))
```

**output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 10
   None  Pain Swelling Tiredness Headache Nausea Malaise Lymph OnlyPainorSwelling
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>              <dbl>
1     0     1        0         0        0      0       1     0                  1
2     0     0        1         0        0      0       0     0                  1
3     0     0        0         0        1      0       0     0                  0
4     1     0        0         0        0      0       0     0                  0
5     0     0        1         0        0      0       0     0                  1
6     0     1        0         1        0      0       0     0                  0
```

**data**

```
df<-read_table("None       Pain    Swelling    Tiredness     Headache     Nausea     Malaise     Lymph   OnlyPainorSwelling
 0         1          0             0            0          0           1         0          1
0         0          1             0            0          0           0         0          1
0         0          0             0            1          0           0         0          0 
1         0          0             0            0          0           0         0          0
0         0          1             0            0          0           0         0          1
0         1          0             1            0          0           0         0          0")

pain_swell = c("Pain", "Swelling")
other_symptoms = c("Tiredness", "Headache", "Nausea", "Malaise", "Lymph")
```